# Nginx flask Gunicorn permission denied to socket file

Tags: python, sockets, nginx, flask, reverse-proxy

I have this Nginx configuration file set up:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

location /flasky {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/flasky.sock;
    }
}
```

I'm using Gunicorn to bind to the socket file while running my app. I changed the ownership of the /tmp directory to www-run:www-run but I'm still getting a permission denied error. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is my Nginx.conf file. It is the default that comes loaded with Nginx when installed:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##

sendfile on;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
keepalive_timeout 65;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;

# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
# gzip_comp_level 6;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Here is the virtual host file I'm trying to use:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsite.com www.mywebsite.com;
    location /flasky {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090; 
        }
    }
```

And finally, the Gunicorn command I am running is:

```
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8090 -w 2 wsgi:applicaiton
```

Comment: Have you tried running with sudo?

Comment: Running what with sudo?

Comment: please attach your full conf file, including any dns conf files. Include what gunicorn settings you are using.

Comment: I’m just curious how one would configure it to at least get it to work on a tcp port. If I can figure that out then implementing a Unix socket is just a simple swap from the port to the socket file.